# Elegently handle property of non-object errors that surface from different locations in code

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

My app reads from a DB that get's written by another API, now in some outlandish cases (that actually happened today) it wrote a customer `id` of 0, which ofcourse, does not exist.

I am looking for an elegant 'from-the-top' model or even presenter solution for handling erroneous ID's that do not exist.

So instead of finding every $whatever->customer->id in my app and then writing in an `isset()`/`empty()` ternary function, I am looking to pacify this error in a more elegant way where any `customer` instantiation/eloquent object would send the string "NA" to a non existent object, so even if an email/phone/etc or any other column of customer model, it would return a simple "NA" string.

I am struggling to find an eloquent solution that would provide **1 point of change**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `withDefault()` modifier on your relationship.

example:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Whatever extends Model {

    public function customer() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id', 'id')
                   ->withDefault([
                       'id' => 'NA',
                       'name' => 'Unknown'
                       // etc
                   ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at a Laravel class that most people don't know about. That is [Fluent](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.html).

It allows you to do stuff like this:

```
$fluent = new Fluent([
    'one' => 1, 
    'two => 2,
]);

echo $fluent->get('one'); // returns 1
echo $fluent->get('three'); // returns null 
echo $fluent->get('three', 3); // returns 3
```

As you can imagine, it's perfect to use with third-party APIs and data that sometimes provide unexpected results. You can also do a lot more with Fluent.

Alternatively, you could look into Laravel helpers such as `array_get()`. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-get):

The `array_get` function retrieves a value from a deeply nested array using "dot" notation:

```
$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

$price = array_get($array, 'products.desk.price');

// 100
```

The `array_get` function also accepts a default value, which will be returned if the specific key is not found:

```
$discount = array_get($array, 'products.desk.discount', 0);

// 0
```